# Wrong redirection in Spring MVC app

Tags: spring, spring-security

Im going to be quick. I have a Spring MVC project, and Im using Spring Security, so after I successfully log in the server redirects me to the application context instead of the index page. Any idea why this is happening, I suspect it may be a security problem, but so far I haven´t figure it out, so please I need help on this one.

My login form action is this: ${loginUrl}
And the redirection problem only happens the first time i try to log in, if I log out and log in again the server redirects me correctly.

Here is my code:

Web Security Config class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    ServicioInicioSesion inicioSesion;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/addUsuarios").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/roles/**", "/usuarios/**").hasAuthority("Administrador")
                .antMatchers("/editarPerfil").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(inicioSesion);
        auth.setMessageSource(messageSource);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder p`enter code here`asswordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
}
```

Index Controller class

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showIndex() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alberto. Try this one:
1 - replace `value = "/index"` by `value = {"/","/index"}`
2 - remove `method` parameter
`@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index"})`

When you submit authentication form in the request you have POST data, but in your case you have `RequestMethod.GET`

Comment: awsome!!, it works now!!!, before i configured the security this worked fine, but at some point it stop working and that was because I modified the index controller. Anyway now is perfect, thank you so much